# How can I make a time by date chart in powerview

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, powerpivot

I am trying to produce a report of when an event first occurs every day.  I'd like to produce a line chart using PowerPivot and Power View that shows the earliest time the event occurs as a line, with the time of day on the Y axis and the date on the X.  I have a PowerPivot table with a list of dates and another column with a list of times.  There are always multiple times per date, and I'd like to select for the earliest and automatically generate the report.

Currently, when I attempt to do so in Power View, if I format the times column as a Decimal Number, I can treat them as a Measure and get the line to work, but the scale of the Y axis is in decimal numbers that are meaningless to anyone who isn't a computer.  Alternatively, if I format the times column as a Date, they are not recognized as measures, so I can't automatically display only the minimum times each day (I can only display the Count).

An adequate solution would also be leaving the data as numbers and having the labels on the Y axis be formatted as dates rather than Excel time values.  Or, if there were a way to force Power View to find the minimum of date-formatted cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work by converting the time values to Excel's decimal time format and then formatting the axis to display as time.  Sort of a funny way to have to do things, but it works.